# 'By' vs 'in' before agent in passive voice sentence

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositions, passive-voice

I would like to know if there is any difference in meaning when you use "by" or "in" before the agent in the passive voice sentence.

The active voice:

> This shop sells all the vegetables.

Passive:

> 1. All the vegetable are sold **in** this shop.
> 2. All the vegetables are sold **by** this shop.

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct, but have slightly different meanings. The first could be used if several vendors operated out of the same shop (which has a monopoly on the vegetable trade). The second can only be used if all vegetable sales go through the shop owner's hands.

Comment: I'm missing the distinction. *By 1890, all the oil in the US was handled **by** Standard Oil* and *By 1890, all the oil in the US was processed **in** Stanard Oil refineries.*

Comment: @deadrat it is not uncommon to have a refining complex where some of the processing is handled by a third party through some form of tolling agreement. For example, standard oil operates the crude unit, the FCC and the hydrotreater, but sinclair oil operates the coker. All the oil is processed **in** Standard's refinery, but it's not all processed **by** Standard.

Comment: You understand that this really isn't about oil refining, right?  But in any case, Standard Oil was broken up because (almost) all the oil in the US *was* processed **by** Standard Oil.  I'm still missing your distinction.

Comment: @deadrat the break up happened because Standard Oil Company conspired to restrain the trade and commerce in petroleum, and to monopolize the commerce in petroleum, in violation of the Sherman Act. the decision did not hinge on the meaning of the words "by" and "in".

Comment: Exactly.  So why did you bring up monopoly in your answer? You claim that *in* and *by* mean "slightly" different things, with the former used for a shop with multiple vendors and the latter only used for a single-owner shop. I could be convinced by evidence, but both usages seem fine to me for describing one of the most famous single-vendor "shops" in history, namely SO.

Comment: @deadrat for two phrasings to seem fine in the same context does not make them absolute synonyms. anyway, the distinction is between shop (location) and shop (merchant).

Comment: There _is_ a fine distinction: 'by' indicates agency more forcibly than 'in' (though of course personification / metonymy is involved, as shops are not sellers), which in turn hints at a single concern.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So you (and jl) claim.  I'd say the distinction was so fine as to go unnoticed, especially in the context of vending.  But I know better than to argue with *two* guys with degrees in chemistry.